# gitlab-runner shows me an error on my server with docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I discover docker. I installed gitlab-runner with a docker image and it works.

i linked gitlab.com to my runner and it works.

However, in the .gitlab-ci.yml when I docker builds I have an error:

> dial tcp: lookup docker on x.x.x.9:53: no such host

```
$ docker info
    Client:
     Context:    default
     Debug Mode: false
    Server:
    ERROR: error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.24/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on x.x.x.9:53: no such host
    errors pretty printing info
```

I can't build my spring-boot image thank